# Message для выбора Itemа в SysListView32

Tags: winapi, функции, события, элементы-управления

Вечер добрый!

Возникла потребность удаленного управления программой Fiddler
Считать-то значения из SysListView32 - считал, используя:

```
SendMessage(hProcess, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, i, lParam(pItem));
```

А вот какое сообщение нужно отправить для выделения пакета (для дальнейшей работы с ним - хз). Я пробовал отловить в Spy++, но там куча месседжей и ни один с выбором элемента (также не исключаю свою криворукость). Также пробовал LVM_SETITEM, но толи я опять же криворукий, толи что - Fiddler тупо перезагружается.

Вот код всей программы:
    unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, ShellApi, Vcl.StdCtrls, CommCtrl;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  PLVItem64 = ^TLVItem64;

  TLVItem64 = packed record
    mask: LongWord;
    iItem: LongInt;
    iSubItem: LongInt;
    state: LongWord;
    stateMask: LongWord;
    alignment1: LongWord;
    pszText: Int64;
    cchTextMax: LongInt;
    iImage: LongInt;
    lParam: Int64;
    iIndent: LongInt;
    iGroupId: LongInt;
    cColumns: LongWord;
    alignment2: LongWord;
    puColumns: Int64;
    piColFmt: Int64;
    iGroup: LongInt;
    alignment3: LongWord;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetSysListView32_x64(AList: TStrings; wnd: THandle): Boolean;
var
  i, ItemCount: Integer;
  Buf: array [0 .. 255] of Char;
  PID, ProcessHandle: DWORD;
  pCh: PChar;
  pItem: PLVItem64;
  Item: TLVItem64;
  hProcess: THandle;
  sL: TStrings;
  Dummy: ULONG_PTR;
  lviRemoteLVItem: LV_ITEM;
  plviRemoteLVItem: PLVItem;
begin
  Result := False;

  hProcess := wnd;
  if hProcess = 0 then
    Exit;

  GetWindowThreadProcessID(hProcess, @PID);
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID);
  if ProcessHandle = 0 then
    Exit;

  pCh := VirtualAllocEx(ProcessHandle, nil, 255, MEM_COMMIT,
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  pItem := VirtualAllocEx(ProcessHandle, nil, SizeOf(TLVItem64), MEM_COMMIT,
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  ItemCount := ListView_GetItemCount(hProcess);

  sL := TStringList.Create;
  try

    for i := 0 to ItemCount - 1 do
    begin
      Item.mask := LVIF_TEXT;
      Item.iItem := i;
      Item.iSubItem := 4;
      Item.pszText := Int64(pCh);
      Item.cchTextMax := SizeOf(Buf);

      WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, pItem, @Item, SizeOf(TLVItem64), Dummy);
      SendMessage(hProcess, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, i, lParam(pItem));
      ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, pCh, @Buf, 255, Dummy);

      sL.Add(Format('%.3d - %s', [i, Buf]));

      if pos('question/questions.json', sL[sL.Count - 1]) > 0 then
        SendMessage(hProcess, LVM_SETITEM, 0, Integer(plviRemoteLVItem));
    end;

    AList.Text := sL.Text;

  finally
    sL.Free;
    VirtualFreeEx(ProcessHandle, pCh, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    VirtualFreeEx(ProcessHandle, pItem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: String;
begin
  Form1.Button1.Enabled := False;
  Form1.Button2.Enabled := False;
  s := GetEnvironmentVariable('HOMEDRIVE') + '\Users\' +             
GetEnvironmentVariable
    ('USERNAME') + '\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler\Fiddler.exe';
  ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PWideChar(s), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
  sleep(5250);
  Form1.Button1.Enabled := True;
  Form1.Button2.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  wnd0, wnd1, wnd2: THandle;

begin
  wnd0 := FindWindow(nil, 'Progress Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger');
  wnd1 := 0;
  wnd2 := 0;

  while (wnd2 = 0) do
  begin
    wnd1 := FindWindowEx(wnd0, wnd1,
      'WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.2bf8098_r6_ad1', nil);
    wnd2 := FindWindowEx(wnd1, 0,
      'WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.2bf8098_r6_ad1', nil);
  end;

  GetSysListView32_x64(Form1.Memo1.Lines, wnd2);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Знаю - тут код на Delphi, но SendMessage он и на африканском SendMessage

Comment: Непонятно что вы хотите. Просто выбрать элемент ListView? Используйте LVM_SETITEMSTATE, например. В принципе и более общий LVM_SETITEM должен работать.

Comment: Да - просто выбрать

Comment: @freim не реагирует на это и все

Comment: А как, по-вашему, та программа должна реагировать? Вы просто устанавливаете некий флажок, при этом программа-владелец об этом даже не будет извещена. Выбор мышью и простая установка флага `LVIS_SELECTED` это совершенно разные вещи. При выборе мышью прежде всего генерируется целый список нотификаций - `LVN_ITEMACTIVATE`, `LVN_ITEMCHANGED`, и т.д. Установка `LVIS_SELECTED` далеко не самое важное что при этом происходит.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прочтете комметы поймете - легко данную задачу не решить
НО! В программе есть управление с клавы и я сделал так

```
SendMessage(wnd2, WM_KEYDOWN, 40, 3243245569);
```

Comment: И так пока не найдет нужную